# Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone em.merge

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

How can I solve this problem? I don't understand the error!

The Exception:

```
    Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-7197] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [Entities.Employe[ matEmp=0 ]], primary key [0].
```

Here is my Code:

```
EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
et.begin();
Employe e = em.find(Employe.class,mat);
e.setNp(np);
em.merge(e);
```

Comment: Please take the time to write complete non-chat/short-message-style questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EclipseLink does not seem to like `0` as primary key.

You can specify that in `persistence.xml`as desribed [here](http://meetrohan.blogspot.de/2011/11/eclipselink-null-primary-key.html).

Comment: Thank you ù i'm solving the prob

Comment: @Userstackoverflow: Then feel free to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: @Userstackoverflow: I guess, you didn't get that? If an answer works for you, you should click on accept.